# как в node.js обрабатывать большие XML-файлы?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xmlparser

есть большой XML-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/xml/my-catalog" catalog-id="my-catalog">
    <category category-id="cat-00000001">... content1 ...</category>
    <category category-id="cat-00000002">... content2 ...</category>
    <category category-id="cat-00000003">... content3 ...</category>
    ...
</catalog>
```

Каждый узел нужно обработать, желательно в потоке не строя DOM для всего документа.
поробовал разные npm-модули - очень неудобно для моих целей...

что конкретно я имею ввиду под обработкой узлов:

- на входе и на выходе xml-файл
- обычое редактирование - удаление, добавление узлов, аттрибутов, контента...
  возможно с условием.
  например: если содержит узел true, то стереть узел ....

почему мне не нравятся event-driven XML-parser:

1. обычно нужно два модуля(бывают и два в одном) - один разбирает, другой собирает.
2. если мне нужно изменить один узел в гигабайтном файле, эти модули перлопачиваюти эти гигабайты: xml -> js, js -> xml...
   ... я не уверен, что они все делают правильно!

Заголовок файла тот-же что и в исходном? аттрибуты, контент правильно вставили?
CDATA? кодировка? комментарии? отступы не забыли?
Каждый узел будет заново переписан! Каждый, Карл!
Мне кажется проще сделать изменение в текстовом редакторе... но иногда нужно программно.

я бы хотел файл разбирать в потоке на куски соответствующие тегам одного уровня, и потом обрабатывать их regex или парсит и собирать

Посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеки, примеры кода или поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Может быть Вам подойдет Service Worker? https://habr.com/ru/company/2gis/blog/345552/

Comment: Для каких именно целей, и чем неудобно? Без этого сложно что-то посоветовать. Я использовал [node-expat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expat), для **моих** целей было достаточно удобно.

Comment: @Yaant добавил немного текста в вопрос

Comment: @Дмытрык не думаю. Service Worker - это вроде браузерная технология... при чем тут XML-parsing?

Comment: _изменить один узел в гигабайтном файле, эти модули перлопачиваюти эти гигабайты_ - естественно. Если в текстовом редакторе делать изменения, точно так же сперва будут прочитаны эти гигабайты, потом записаны.

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее. :) Честно говоря, я как-то плохо себе представляю себе не event-driven потоковый парсер для произвольного XML. Наверно, для XML заранее известной структуры, еще можно что-то придумать (какой-нибудь специфический Transform stream, например), но вряд ли Вы найдете модуль, заточенный именно под Ваши XML.